# Question between symmetric matrix and transforming to other bases?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is symmetric and $A^{10} = 0$, then $A$ must be $0$.

I was thinking that $A$ must have as many eigenvalues as it does rank, and from that statement,
one of its eigenvalues must be $0$, but since it will have $n-1$ other eigenvalues, it cannot be zero?

And furthermore, if we diagonalize $A$, and we have alternative basis $X$, if we want
$A^27$, then diagonalized, it would be equivalent to $A^{27} = X B^{27}X^{-1}$, where $B$ is a matrix with eigenvalues. If $B^3$ so happens to be the identity matrix, then we can convert to $A^27 = X (I)^9 X^{-1}$, then $A^{27}$ is equivalent to the identity matrix?

Note: I'm not sure whether it's possible for a similar matrix to $A$ (since it would be composed of $A$'s eigenvalues, to be equivalent to the identity matrix after taking it to the $n$th power)

Comment: All the eigenvalues must be $0$, given your assumption. Hence $A$ is diagonalizable (if you mean real symmetric) and its spectrum is $\{0\}$. So $A=P^{-1}0P=0$.

Comment: This is easier than anything involving eigenvalues. $A^{10} = \left(AA\right)^5 = \left(AA^T\right)^5$, with $AA^T$ being symmetric. Moreover, if $AA^T=0$ then $A=0$ by a famous (and easy) fact about real matrices. Now, you have reduced your question to the analogous question with the exponent $5$ in place of $10$. But $5 < 6$, and you can reduce $6$ down to $3$. Then again, $3 < 4$, and $4$ reduces to $2$, and $2$ to $1$.